# Crystal Report - Printing conditional count in Group header

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have been looking for days for an answer, so im hoping I can shed some light on this topic here. I have not been working with crystal reports for very long, so I am going to give as much detail as possible.

I am using VB.net (2005) to generate a crystal report. The crystal report used a View I created within my database. I can access all data and display values correctly.

I have a group in my report that groups by an Identifier field. I also have a Boolean field entitled ‘Passed’ which is either true or false reflecting if the board with that given identifier passed or failed testing.

As an example, lets say a board with identifier: `xxxxxx` has 6 records, 3 true and 3 false (meaning it passed 3 times and failed 3 times). I was asked to give a total of the board testing history in the group header detailing how many times it passed and failed testing.

- I have looked into keeping a running total, but that will be incorrect because running totals can only be displayed correctly after the records are evaluated (the records have not been evaluated until the header has already been printed).
- I tried going the route of a shared or global variable, with the variable being incremented in the details section, it being reset in the group footer, and displayed in the group header. This might produce the correct values, but print them in the start of the next group, not the current group.
- I also tried using a Count expression but I could not find anything on how to make it conditional the way I need.
- I could do it in a subreport, but I think there is a better way.

Does anyone have any ideas or at least hints of a way I could achieve this without using a subreport?

Answer (score 0):

In details section add one formula, In that formula define shared variables. Assign count of passed identifier to one shared variable and failed identifier to other shared variable.

In group header add two formulas (one for passed and other for failed) and put below code

```
shared numbervar num;

num;
```

Note that here num is an example shared variable name. You will have to replace it with your shared variable name mentioned in detail section.

In group footer add another two formulas and set the shared variable values to 0.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tries to do as instructed, but all I get is values of zero. how are you expecting me to produce the count of  passed (or failed). I am trying to do it with-   ' If {BoardTestHistory.Passed} = true then CountPassed := CountPassed + 1 else if {BoardTestHistory.Passed} = false then CountFailed :=CountFailed + 1;' do i need to use a count formula instead? Thanks.

Comment: this is the entire formula I added in the details section-     'Shared numbervar CountPassed;
Shared numbervar CountFailed;

WhileprintingRecords;
 If {BoardTestHistory.Passed} = true then CountPassed := CountPassed + 1 else if {BoardTestHistory.Passed} = false then CountFailed :=CountFailed + 1;'

Comment: I put exactly as you said, and the display in the details sections displays count passed and it is correct. The value in the group header is still wrong though. my reset code looks like this- 'WhilePrintingRecords;
shared numbervar CountPassed;
CountPassed:=0 ;'         and  my display code in the group header looks like this-     'WhileprintingRecords;
Shared numbervar CountPassed;

CountPassed;'.  Sorry about formatting and all. I am new to posting and also new to crystal reports. thanks.

Comment: yes, they both (passed and failed count) display as 0 in the footer.

Comment: Is this what you were asking? Its probably something extremely easy I am missing, I just cant see it. Does case of variables matter? I believe I am using the same case through all variable instances.

Comment: I just tried at my end. Here is what I did, I placed detail formulas in group header.and in group footer added formula for reset. It is working at my end.
My header formula contains

shared numbervar num;
if {@test} <> 0 then 
num := num + {Command.WALT} * ({Command.GLeaseArea}/{@test});

Comment: I dont understand. you are saying you took the details formula and moved it to the group Header? I dont know what all of these variables are; @test and {Command.WALT} * ({Command.GLeaseArea}/{@test})?

Comment: Sorry. Those are columns from my crystal report. Just refer the syntax. My footer formula is shared numbervar num:=0;
Make sure your code syntax is as mine.

Comment: It is the same in the footer as what you are saying-   
shared numbervar CountPassed:=0 ;

CountPassed;     With only the count passed variable at the end so I can see the value. it prints 0 each time in the footer. is that what im expecting?

Comment: Group Footer is ok. Put detail section formula in group header section instead of detail section. remove formula from detail section.

Answer (score 0):

For some identifier you have 6 records out of 6 3 are passed and 3 are failed now you want to show the count of records on the header. `Below solution will satisfy this problem.`

createa formula

```
`If <Field=false>
then 1
else 0`
```

now place this condition in detail section and take the sum of the values, similarly do the same for `true` and place it in detail section.

`Now you have the counts saperately for both true and false`

Now create another formula and paste the below code and place it in group header section.

```
EvaluateAfter({above created forumla});

Sum ({above created formula}, {ORDERDETAIL.DATEE})
```

Perform the same operation for `true` and place it in group header.

Now you have the count in group headers

Comment: This worked! thank you very much Pratik and Siva for helping me with this issue.